# How to make checked checkbox value in array

Tags: php, php-5.6

I want to do edit form,user already value is selected means I want to display in edit form in checked checkbox value,so I am trying like this

```
<?php 
include("dbconfig.php");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM residential_propertytype WHERE status !='1'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($pr_type = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
$propty[] = $pr_type;

}
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($propty);
echo "</pre>";
foreach($propty as $res)
        {
        $checked = in_array($res['id'], 5) ? 'checked' : '';
        ?>

        <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $res['id']?>" <?php echo $checked; ?>><?php echo $res['propertyName']?>
        <?php
        }
?>
```

See below **var_dump($propty)** I am getting answer like this

```
array(10) {


[0]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "Apartment"
    ["propertyName"]=>
    string(9) "Apartment"
    [2]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["reg_date"]=>
    string(0) ""
    [3]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "Villament"
    ["propertyName"]=>
    string(9) "Villament"
    [2]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["reg_date"]=>
    string(0) ""
    [3]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [1]=>
    string(16) "Individual House"
    ["propertyName"]=>
    string(16) "Individual House"
    [2]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["reg_date"]=>
    string(0) ""
    [3]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "Row House"
    ["propertyName"]=>
    string(9) "Row House"
    [2]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["reg_date"]=>
    string(0) ""
    [3]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "Villa"
    ["propertyName"]=>
    string(5) "Villa"
    [2]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["reg_date"]=>
    string(0) ""
    [3]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "Plot"
    ["propertyName"]=>
    string(4) "Plot"
    [2]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["reg_date"]=>
    string(0) ""
    [3]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "7"
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "7"
    [1]=>
    string(13) "Builder Floor"
    ["propertyName"]=>
    string(13) "Builder Floor"
    [2]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["reg_date"]=>
    string(0) ""
    [3]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "8"
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "8"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "Penthouse"
    ["propertyName"]=>
    string(9) "Penthouse"
    [2]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["reg_date"]=>
    string(0) ""
    [3]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "9"
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "9"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "Farm House"
    ["propertyName"]=>
    string(10) "Farm House"
    [2]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["reg_date"]=>
    string(0) ""
    [3]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [9]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "10"
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "10"
    [1]=>
    string(16) "Studio Apartment"
    ["propertyName"]=>
    string(16) "Studio Apartment"
    [2]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["reg_date"]=>
    string(0) ""
    [3]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```

While going to make the checked checkbox value I am getting error **Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, integer given** how to resolve this issue

Comment: Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php. Second parameter should be the array.

Comment: The warning is telling you how to fix it.  You need to pass an `array`, but you are passing `5` which is an integer.

Comment: how can i pass please update your answer

Comment: Did you give up or what???

Answer (score 0):

You need to define, probably what you meant about `5` ..

It should be like: $array_list = array ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

```
$checked = in_array($res['id'], $array_list) ? 'checked' : '';
```

On your example, you are passing `5` instead of an `array`

Answer (score 0):

You know the value and the array key that you want to match, why use `in_array()`?

```
 $checked = ($res['id'] == 5) ? 'checked' : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML form code, the checkbox(es) that you want to make an array all need to be named the same thign wtih a bracket on the end.  This way the checkboxes selected will form an array in the $_POST array

```
<form method=post action=yourstuff.php>
Pick your favorite pizza toppings -
<input type=checkbox name=topping[] value="pepperoni"> Pepperoni <br />
<input type=checkbox name=topping[] value="ex. chz"> Extra cheese <br />
<input type=checkbox name=topping[] value="black olives"> Black olives <br />
<input type=submit>
</form>
```